# How has number of featured questions changed?

Tags: support, bounty, statistics

Is it possible to find somewhere how the number of [featured questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) (i.e., questions with bounties) evolved. For example, can I find out what was the number of featured questions a year ago? Or an average number of featured questions per month?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to write a data.SE query to find which questions had bounties, and when they were placed. And if one wants to be particularly clever also when they were ended, so one can find the number of featured questions in a given day like that. Seems like a lot of work, to do all that, though.